# use distinct keyword for 3 tables in sql server?

Tags: sql-server

I want to use distinct keyword for 3 different tables like `intern_data_copy`, `fresher_data_copy`, `exp1_data`.

These tables have three different columns. Now I want to use join in then and also use use distinct for that column.

```
select DISTINCT a.sec_s, b.sec_skill, c.sec_sk 
from intern_data_copy a 
JOIN fresher_data_copy b ON a.fflag = b.fflag 
JOIN exp1_data c ON b.fflag = c.fflag
```

the output comes in distinct format but for every table. if "java" or ".net" is in 2 different table then it is showing 2 times.

if a data like "java" is available in all of three tables than i want to see it only once.
How can I achieve this.

thanks in advance

Comment: The `DISTINCT` keyword will apply to the set of **rows** you're getting, e.g. there won't be any duplicate sets of these three columns... but I don't completely understand if that's what you want, or if not, what you really want......

Comment: Try to avoid using distinct if possible. On larger datasets it can be quite slow. Try to use GROUP BY clause...

Comment: @marc_S, your terminology can be misleading to OP's level ("duplicate sets(?) of these three columns"; instead of sets you might say instances or possibly more clearly: no two rows that are returned in the result will have the same value for all columns).

Comment: @pra..., as marc_s said it is not clear what should be the purpose of your query (since you are not selecting fflag). It returns only a set of skills (but for who/what?).

Comment: @YvesM - In SQL Server there is no performance benefit to using `GROUP BY` instead of `DISTINCT`

Answer (score 1):

You could try (I am assuming a few things, so this is a guess):

```
SELECT fflag, a.sec_s
FROM intern_data_copy a 
UNION 
SELECT fflag, b.sec_skill
FROM fresher_data_copy b
UNION
SELECT fflag, c.sec_sk
FROM exp1_data c
```

but you must clarify your question if you want to see answers and not guesses.

Comment: +1 I must be assuming something more or less identical to what you are assuming.